# Command Line Password Prompt in PHP

Tags: php, passwords

I'm writing a command line tool to help my web app. It needs a password to connect to the service. I'd like the script to show a password prompt so I don't have to pass it as a command line argument.

That's easy enough, but I'd like it to not echo the password to the screen as it's typed. How can I do this with PHP?

Bonus points for doing it in pure PHP (no `system('stty')`) and replacing the characters with `*`.

**EDIT:**

The script will run on a unix like system (linux or mac). The script is written in PHP, and will most likely stay like that.

Also, for the record, the `stty` way of doing it is:

```
echo "Password: ";
system('stty -echo');
$password = trim(fgets(STDIN));
system('stty echo');
// add a new line since the users CR didn't echo
echo "\n";
```

I'd prefer to not have the `system()` calls in there.

Comment: What OS will the command line script run on? Will the command line script be written in PHP or the OS's batch scripting language?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Found on [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/05/01/interactive-cli-password-prompt-in-php/).

```
function prompt_silent($prompt = "Enter Password:") {
  if (preg_match('/^win/i', PHP_OS)) {
    $vbscript = sys_get_temp_dir() . 'prompt_password.vbs';
    file_put_contents(
      $vbscript, 'wscript.echo(InputBox("'
      . addslashes($prompt)
      . '", "", "password here"))');
    $command = "cscript //nologo " . escapeshellarg($vbscript);
    $password = rtrim(shell_exec($command));
    unlink($vbscript);
    return $password;
  } else {
    $command = "/usr/bin/env bash -c 'echo OK'";
    if (rtrim(shell_exec($command)) !== 'OK') {
      trigger_error("Can't invoke bash");
      return;
    }
    $command = "/usr/bin/env bash -c 'read -s -p \""
      . addslashes($prompt)
      . "\" mypassword && echo \$mypassword'";
    $password = rtrim(shell_exec($command));
    echo "\n";
    return $password;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does not work on Windows 7. According to various online forums, won't work on anything else than Windows XP and 2003 Server.

Comment: See my answer below (or go to https://github.com/Seldaek/hidden-input directly) for a solution that works from XP up to 7, 32/64bit, and no ugly prompt popping up.

Comment: VBS and bash? We should throw in a few more languages.

Comment: `rtrim` could strip valid characters (i.e., any whitespace ending the string), but you can omit it and use `echo -n` instead.

Comment: @JMW 's solution at the bottom of this page works for Windows 7 64. Probably will work on Win 7 32 as well. It's only a few lines, does the job and only requires that Powershell be installed.

Answer (score 11):

Depending on your environment (i.e., not on Windows), you can use the ncurses library (specifically, the [ncurses_noecho()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ncurses-noecho.php) function to stop keyboard echo and [ncurses_getch()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ncurses-getch.php) to read the input) to get the password without displaying it on screen.

Answer (score 9):

You can use my [hiddeninput.exe](https://github.com/Seldaek/hidden-input) file to get real hidden input without leaking the information anywhere on screen.

```
<?php

echo 'Enter password: ';
$password = exec('hiddeninput.exe');
echo PHP_EOL;

echo 'Password was: ' . $password . PHP_EOL;
```

If you remove the last echo, the password should never show up, but you can use that for validation obvoiusly.

Comment: I am sure that hiddeninput.exe from the project is not a massive security threat.. but it is just not good practice to use random binary blobs from the internet to handle passwords. Even if this code is secure, it is just a placeholder for a malicious actor to inject something nasty...

Comment: Hahahahahahahahahahahahahahahah.exe

Answer (score 6):

The below method works under Linux CLI but not under Windows CLI or Apache. It also only works with chars in the standard Ascii table (It would not take much to make it compatible with extended char sets though).

I have put a bit of code in to protect against copy and paste passwords. If the bit between the two comments is removed then a password can be injected/pasted in.

I hope this helps someone.

```
<?php

    echo("Password: ");
    $strPassword=getObscuredText();
    echo("\n");
    echo("You entered: ".$strPassword."\n");

    function getObscuredText($strMaskChar='*')
    {
        if(!is_string($strMaskChar) || $strMaskChar=='')
        {
            $strMaskChar='*';
        }
        $strMaskChar=substr($strMaskChar,0,1);
        readline_callback_handler_install('', function(){});
        $strObscured='';
        while(true)
        {
            $strChar = stream_get_contents(STDIN, 1);
            $intCount=0;
// Protect against copy and paste passwords
// Comment \/\/\/ to remove password injection protection
            $arrRead = array(STDIN);
            $arrWrite = NULL;
            $arrExcept = NULL;
            while (stream_select($arrRead, $arrWrite, $arrExcept, 0,0) && in_array(STDIN, $arrRead))            
            {
                stream_get_contents(STDIN, 1);
                $intCount++;
            }
//        /\/\/\
// End of protection against copy and paste passwords
            if($strChar===chr(10))
            {
                break;
            }
            if ($intCount===0)
            {
                if(ord($strChar)===127)
                {
                    if(strlen($strObscured)>0)
                    {
                        $strObscured=substr($strObscured,0,strlen($strObscured)-1);
                        echo(chr(27).chr(91)."D"." ".chr(27).chr(91)."D");
                    }
                }
                elseif ($strChar>=' ')
                {
                    $strObscured.=$strChar;
                    echo($strMaskChar);
                    //echo(ord($strChar));
                }
            }
        }
        readline_callback_handler_remove();
        return($strObscured);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Would be significantly improved with an introductory minimal version which doesn't print asterisks, prevent copy-paste, handle delete, etc: yet, this should still likely be the accepted answer, given the edited question; and the extra sophistication to handle strings correctly is cool.

Answer (score 4):

This is the easiest solution for all platforms:

```
function prompt($message = 'prompt: ', $hidden = false) {
    if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli') {
        return false;
    }
    echo $message;
    $ret = 
        $hidden
        ? exec(
            PHP_OS === 'WINNT' || PHP_OS === 'WIN32'
            ? __DIR__ . '\prompt_win.bat'
            : 'read -s PW; echo $PW'
        )
        : rtrim(fgets(STDIN), PHP_EOL)
    ;
    if ($hidden) {
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Then create `prompt_win.bat` in the same directory:

```
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "Line="
For /F %%# In ('"Prompt;$H & For %%# in (1) Do Rem"') Do (
    Set "BS=%%#"
)

:loop_start
    Set "Key="
    For /F "delims=" %%# In ('Xcopy /L /W "%~f0" "%~f0" 2^>Nul') Do (
        If Not Defined Key (
            Set "Key=%%#"
        )
    )
    Set "Key=%Key:~-1%"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If Not Defined Key (
        Goto :loop_end
    )
    If %BS%==^%Key% (
        Set "Key="
        If Defined Line (
            Set "Line=!Line:~0,-1!"
        )
    )
    If Not Defined Line (
        EndLocal
        Set "Line=%Key%"
    ) Else (
        For /F "delims=" %%# In ("!Line!") Do (
            EndLocal
            Set "Line=%%#%Key%"
        )
    )
    Goto :loop_start
:loop_end

Echo;!Line!
```

Comment: `rtrim` could strip valid characters (i.e., any whitespace ending the string), but you can omit it and use `echo -n` instead.

Comment: This gives `read: Illegal option -s` on `Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS`

Comment: `/bin/sh` doesn't support `-s` etc, you have to use `/bin/bash`. I think you can use something like `exec( '/bin/bash -c "read ..." ')`, but it gets clunky with escaping the quotes

Answer (score 3):

**Works on every windows system, that has powershell support.** (source from: http://www.qxs.ch/2013/02/08/php-cli-password-prompts-on-windows-7/ )

```
<?php
// please set the path to your powershell, here it is: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
$pwd=shell_exec('C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "$Password=Read-Host -assecurestring \"Please enter your password\" ; $PlainPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Password)) ; echo $PlainPassword;"');
$pwd=explode("\n", $pwd); $pwd=$pwd[0];
echo "You have entered the following password: $pwd\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
system('stty -echo');
```

to disable the current terminal echo, and:

```
system('stty echo');
```

to reenable it. Set it before and after `fgets`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that there is no simple way of doing it (actually I can't think of any way) without using stty -echo.
If you intent running it on windows, you could create a batch script that would provide the unechoed typed info to your php script.

```
@echo off
cls
SET /P uname=Enter Username:
echo hP1X500P[PZBBBfh#b##fXf-V@`$fPf]f3/f1/5++u5>in.com
set /p password=Enter password :<nul
for /f “tokens=*” %%i in (’in.com’) do set password=%%i
del in.com
echo.
c:\php\php.exe d:\php\test.php %uname% “%password%”
Pause
```

example taken from http://www.indiangnu.org/2008/php-hide-user-input-using-batch-script-windows/

Comment: nice trick to create a text-only COM file (looks a bit like the EICAR anti-virus test ;-) ) unfortunately this wont work under 64-bit Windows... (no more 16-bit COM support... and creating a EXE file this way... good luck!)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is not good enough. First of all, the Windows solution doesn't work on Windows 7 and above. The solution for other OSs depends on Bash and bash built-in 'read'. However, there are systems which does not use Bash (eg. OpenBSD) and where this obviously won't work.

In this [blog](https://blog.dsl-platform.com/hiding-input-from-console-in-php/) I've discussed solution which works on almost any Unix based OS and Windows from 95 to 8. The Windows solution uses external program written in C on top Win32 API. The solution for other OSs uses external command 'stty'. I have yet to see a Unix based system which does not have 'stty'

Comment: I think it will be better if you provide a concise version of your post here (may be with only examples for each approach), cause simply posting a link is against the initial idea of SE sites.

Comment: Is there an generic library that offers the ability to prompt the user for passwords, normal plain text, and menu options all cross platform?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai No, there isn't. Such feature is not implemented in PHP, so it can't be done using only PHP. There is a ncurses PHP extension but it doesn't work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an SSH connection? You can abstract the commands away, redirect input/output and have full control.

You can provide someone with a pure clean shell with as little rights as neccesary, and let the password just be POST'ed along with to SSH2::Connect() to open the shell.

I created a nice class to work with the php SSH2 extension, maybe it helps you;
(and it also does secure file transfers)

```
<?php

/**
 * SSH2
 * 
 * @package Pork
 * @author SchizoDuckie
 * @version 1.0
 * @access public
 */
class SSH2
{
    private $host;
    private $port;
    private $connection;
    private $timeout;
    private $debugMode;
    private $debugPointer;
    public $connected; 
    public $error;


    /**
     * SSH2::__construct()
     * 
     * @param mixed $host
     * @param integer $port
     * @param integer $timeout
     * @return
     */
    function __construct($host, $port=22, $timeout=10)
    {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->port = $port;
        $this->timeout = 10;
        $this->error = 'not connected';
        $this->connection = false;
        $this->debugMode = Settings::Load()->->get('Debug', 'Debugmode');
        $this->debugPointer = ($this->debugMode) ? fopen('./logs/'.date('Y-m-d--H-i-s').'.log', 'w+') : false;
        $this->connected = false;

    }


    /**
     * SSH2::connect()
     * 
     * @param mixed $username
     * @param mixed $password
     * @return
     */
    function connect($username, $password)
    {
        $this->connection = ssh2_connect($this->host, $this->port);
        if (!$this->connection) return $this->error("Could not connect to {$this->host}:{$this->port}");
        $this->debug("Connected to {$this->host}:{$this->port}");
        $authenticated = ssh2_auth_password($this->connection, $username, $password);
        if(!$authenticated) return $this->error("Could not authenticate: {$username}, check your password");
        $this->debug("Authenticated successfully as {$username}");
        $this->connected = true;

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * SSH2::exec()
     *
     * @param mixed $command shell command to execute
     * @param bool $onAvailableFunction a function to handle any available data.
     * @param bool $blocking blocking or non-blocking mode. This 'hangs' php execution until the command has completed if you set it to true. If you just want to start an import and go on, use this icm onAvailableFunction and false
     * @return
     */
    function exec($command, $onAvailableFunction=false, $blocking=true)
    {
        $output = '';
        $stream = ssh2_exec($this->connection, $command);
        $this->debug("Exec: {$command}");
        if($onAvailableFunction !== false)
        {
            $lastReceived = time();
            $timeout =false;
            while (!feof($stream) && !$timeout)
            {
                $input = fgets($stream, 1024);
                if(strlen($input) >0)
                {
                    call_user_func($onAvailableFunction, $input);
                    $this->debug($input);
                    $lastReceived = time();
                }
                else
                {
                    if(time() - $lastReceived >= $this->timeout)
                    {
                        $timeout = true;
                        $this->error('Connection timed out');
                        return($this->error);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if($blocking === true && $onAvailableFunction === false)
        {
            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
            $output = stream_get_contents($stream);
            $this->debug($output);
        }
        fclose($stream);
        return($output);
    }


    /**
     * SSH2::createDirectory()
     *
     * Creates a directory via sftp
     *
     * @param string $dirname
     * @return boolean success
     *  
     */
    function createDirectory($dirname)
    {
        $ftpconnection = ssh2_sftp ($this->connection);
        $dircreated = ssh2_sftp_mkdir($ftpconnection, $dirname, true);
        if(!$dircreated) 
        {
            $this->debug("Directory not created: ".$dirname);
        }
        return $dircreated;
    }

    public function listFiles($dirname)
    {
        $input = $this->exec(escapeshellcmd("ls  {$dirname}"));
        return(explode("\n", trim($input)));

    }

    public function sendFile($filename, $remotename)
    {
        $this->debug("sending {$filename} to {$remotename} ");
        if(file_exists($filename) && is_readable($filename))
        {
            $result = ssh2_scp_send($this->connection, $filename, $remotename, 0664);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->debug("Unable to read file : ".$filename);
            return false;
        }
        if(!$result) $this->debug("Failure uploading {$filename} to {$remotename}");
        return $result;
    }

    public function getFile($remotename, $localfile)
    {
        $this->debug("grabbing {$remotename} to {$localfile}");
        $result = ssh2_scp_recv($this->connection, $remotename, $localfile);

        if(!$result) $this->debug("Failure downloading {$remotename} to {$localfile}");
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * SSH2::debug()
     * 
     * @param mixed $message
     * @return
     */
    function debug($message) 
    {
        if($this->debugMode)
        {
            fwrite($this->debugPointer, date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." : ".$message."\n");
        }
    }



    /**
     * SSH2::error()
     * 
     * @param mixed $errorMsg
     * @return
     */
    function error($errorMsg) 
    {
        $this->error = $errorMsg;
        $this->debug($errorMsg);
        return false;
    }   

    /**
     * SSH2::__destruct()
     * 
     * @return
     */
    function __destruct() 
    {
        if($this->connection){
            $this->connection = null;
        }
        if($this->debugMode && $this->debugPointer)
        {
            fclose($this->debugPointer);
        }
    }       


}
```

Usage example:

```
$settings = Settings::Load()->Get("SecureServer");
$ssh = new SSH2($settings['host']);
if( $ssh->connect($settings['username'], $settings['password']))
{
    echo $ssh->exec("ls -la ".$settings['path'], false, true);  
    flush();    
}
```

Comment: i am getting error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Settings' not found in /home/tester/tools/SSH/conn_ssh3.php on line 2, i named the ssh2 class as Settings.php, and also tried to change the Settings::Load() to SSH2::Load()

Answer (score 0):

Theorically you can do it using stream_set_blocking(), but looks like there are some PHP bugs managing STDIN.

Look:
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34972
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36030

Try yourself:

```
echo "Enter Password: ";
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin','r');
// Trying to disable stream blocking
stream_set_blocking($stdin, FALSE) or die ('Failed to disable stdin blocking');
// Trying to set stream timeout to 1sec
stream_set_timeout ($stdin, 1) or die ('Failed to enable stdin timeout');
```

Comment: Snippet seems to be missing the line to read in from stdin to get the password; but this answer is at least not assuming a Windows CLI like so many others, and is answering the "no system calls" and "pure PHP" parts of the edited question.