# PHP: How to use STDIN to get secret input for passwords on Linux based systems

Tags: php, command-line-interface

What is the most up-to-date way to get input from STDIN but not see what was typed in PHP CLI mode, so things like passwords are not shown?

Difference being, only on Linux based systems like Ubuntu, most other answers seem to be based on Windows support, it is not clear which is the best way for Linux?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command Line Password Prompt in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187736/command-line-password-prompt-in-php)

Comment: @rickdenhaan Nope, most of the answers are for Windows and the rest are outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that if terminal has `stty` available

```
<?php

shell_exec('stty -echo');

echo 'Enter pw: ';
$value = fgets(STDIN, 4096);

shell_exec('stty echo');

var_dump($value);
```

If you need the fancy asterisk you could use `systemd-ask-password` if that's available

```
<?php

$value = shell_exec('systemd-ask-password "Enter pw:"');

var_dump($value);
```

Read more here: https://learnfromnoobs.com/hide-user-input-password/

Comment: After research, it seems like the stty method is the best way right now, I just got the terminal mode with `stty -g` and set it after disabling echo.